# Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") :

Tags: r, regressão

Estou rodando regressões lineares múltiplas no R. Inicialmente rodei com o efeito "pooled" e funcionou bem. Quando tento fazer o mesmo com o efeito "within" e "random" apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") :    invalid to set
>   the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was
>   0)

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz do erro que estou cometendo? Aproveito para me desculpar se eu estiver fazendo algo muito idiota.

```
##INSTALAÇÃO DE PACOTES##
list.of.packages <- c("AER","tidyverse", "gdata","DT","ggthemes", "RCurl", "readxl", "zoo", "ggcorrplot", "reprex", "ggmap","ggalt",  "devtools", "gapminder", "gganimate", "cowplot", "xts", "PerformanceAnalytics", "fmsb", "viridis", "tidyverse", "sandwich", "lmtest", "qqman", "car", "dplyr", "stargazer", "ggplot2", "foreign","openintro", "nlme", "OIdata", "gdata", "pdflscape", "doBy","ivpack", "gplots", "psych","plm","cluster.datasets", "readxl")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
lapply(list.of.packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
##

## CAMINHO DO PROJETO## 
library(readxl)
library(plm)
Dados <- read_excel("Testes/Dissertreg.xlsx")


##DECLARAÇÃO de VARIÁVEIS
Y <- cbind(Produtividade)
X <- cbind(Racao, Silagem, Preco)

##SETANDO DADOS EM PAINEL
pdata <- pdata.frame(Dados, index=c("id", "t")) 


##ESTATÍSTICA DESCRITIVA
summary(Y)
summary(X)

##Pooled OLS Estimator
pooling <- plm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, model = "pooling")
summary(pooling)

##Efeito Fixo ou within
fixo <- plm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, model = "within")
summay(fixo)

##Efeito Aleatório
random <- plm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, model = "random")
summary(random)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Breve explicação (ou nem tanto)

O erro está na chamada da função `plm`. Veja que a fórmula, primeiro argumento, deve refletir a relação entre as variáveis presentes no segundo argumento (`data`).

Desse modo, o que ocorre é que o `R` busca `X` e `Y` em `pdata`, não encontra essas variáveis lá, porque elas não existem, e então, seguindo as regras de escopo do `R`, vai buscá-las em seu ambiente global e encontra. Mas ai ocorre que Y definido no ambiente global tem uma incompatibilidade com a função `plm` e aquele erro aparece.

Vamos a reprodução do erro e a sua solução.

### Reprodução do Erro

Como você não ofereceu uma forma de reproduzirmos o seus dados, vou usar os dados da documentação da função, mas vou reproduzir os erros.

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
Y <- cbind(Grunfeld$inv)
X <- cbind(Grunfeld$value, Grunfeld$capital)
erro <- plm(Y ~ X, data = Grunfeld, model = "random")
```

> Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") : 
>     inválido especificar a classe como matriz a não ser que o atributo de dimensão tenha comprimento 2 (0 encontrado)

### Solução

Para resolver esse problema, mas trocar o `Y ~ X` na fórmula pelas variáveis que os compõe. Assim teríamos:

```
mod1 <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "random")
mod1

#> Model Formula: inv ~ value + capital
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       value     capital 
#>   -57.83441     0.10978     0.30811
```

E o mesmo serve para os outros tipos de modelos:

```
mod2 <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "pooling")
mod3 <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within")
```

Comment: Já agora, o erro vem de um `cbind` a mais, `Y <- Grunfeld$inv` chega e o resto do código já corre sem erros. Com `cbind` o vetor resposta é um objeto de classe `"matrix"`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.